# Is it possible to create a hotspot from an Ubuntu guest in VirtualBox only with a USB dongle from a wireless keyboard?

Tags: virtualbox

The question is applicable for the guest OS, which is Ubuntu, same like the host OS.

I am interested to create a hotspot from the Ubuntu guest(VirtualBox), only with the help of a USB dongle from a wireless keyboard. I am not sure if it does matter, the host and the guest use a Wi-Fi network to connect to the internet. If it matters, could it work if I will connect the device to the internet through a Ethernet cable, instead of a Wi-Fi?

Comment: You want to use the USB dongle from a keyboard to set up a hotspot that other people can connect to over WiFi? 

Comment: Indeed @Matigo, it is only one of my thoughts, only for my devices. Regards.